# Get File Name from a Path in Listbox Item

Tags: c#

I want to reduce the length of the path and display only the file name.

For example, suppose the path is `c:\\program files\...\123.jpg` I want to display only `123.jpg`.

Here is the code I have been working with thus far. Can anyone suggest modifications?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel3.Controls.Clear();
    var ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    ofd.Multiselect = true;
    ofd.Filter = "DICOM Files (*.dcm;*.dic)|*.dcm;*.dic|All Files (*.*)|*.*";

    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
        return;
    foreach (string s in ofd.FileNames)
    {  
        listBox1.Items.Add(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at the `Path` class, __lots__ of helpful methods in there! Also you may want to store the full path in the Items' __Tags__.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a class named [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.Path%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in `System.IO namespace`.
Between its numerous static methods you could find

```
 Path.GetFilename(string);
```

Using it in your Add loop you could set only the filenames

```
listBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(s));
```

However, I suggest to save the folder name somewhere, because if you need to process these files you need it. And, guess what, Path has a method also to extract a path from a full filename

```
if(filenames.Length > 0)
     string workingPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(filenames[0]);
```

**EDIT**
From your comments below it seems that you call this button_click more than one time and every time you select a different folder. In this case, stripping the path part from the selected filenames leaves your listbox filled with files that you can't retrieve because you don't know the path part (stripped away). If you need to retrieve the files selected to execute some kind of process, then you need to store somewhere the full path of these files and be able to retrive them.
You can achieve this result storing the files selected in a `List<string>` instance.

Declare at the global level a variable to store these full filenames
(Add `using System.Collection.Generic;`)

```
List<string> selectedFiles = new List<string>();
```

Now inside the button click add the full filename to the `List<string>` and the stripped file to the ListBox items, in the same order

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel3.Controls.Clear();
    var ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    ofd.Multiselect = true;
    ofd.Filter = "DICOM Files (*.dcm;*.dic)|*.dcm;*.dic|All Files (*.*)|*.*";

    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
        return;

    foreach (string s in ofd.FileNames)
    {  
        listBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(s));
        selectedFiles.Add(s);
    }
}
```

Now, if you want to retrieve the full path for the selected file in the listbox you could use

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   if(listBox1.SelectedIndex >= 0)
   {
       string fullFileName = selectedFiles[listBox1.SelectedIndex];
       .... process the filename ....
   }
}
```

Comment: There is not to much to elaborate here, just change the line that add the items in the listbox. (and add a `using System.IO;` at the beginning of your file)

Comment: while using for one directory its ok but when i want from another directory??

Comment: @MaheshMahi - This line of code will return the output you specified in your question - regardless of the different directories. Are you saying you wish to be able to navigate to the directory again with this listbox? If so, thats a different question.

Comment: its not the question here i want only to get the file name either i select the file from any directory .. is it possible..?

Comment: Yes, when you change the directory, the code will always extract from the filenames only the file part. Of course stripping the folder from a full filename leaves the possibility to have two files with the same filename. Then, how I have said, its up to you to save somewhere the stripped path part to rebuild the correct full filename

Answer (score 0):

Use `Path.GetFileName()` to return the name

see [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: You should include an example of how you expect the OP to use this

Comment: string path = @"C:\mydir\"; we have to mention the path but what if we want to change the path while selecting the file